# Real integration theorem (Laplace transform)

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

> *Real Integration Theorem*
>
> This theorem establishes the relationship between the **Laplace** transform of a function and **that** of its integral.
>   It states that
>   $$
>     \mathscr{L}\left[ \int_0^t f(t) \,\text{d}t \right]
>   = \frac{1}{s} F(s)
> $$
>   The proof of this theorem is carried out by integrating the definition of the **Laplace** transform by parts.
>   This proof is similar to that of the real differentiation theorem and is left as an exercise.
>   The **Laplace** transform of the $n$th intgegral of a function is the transform of the function divides by $s^n$.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ZqU.png).)

Hello. I would like to check whether my solving is right or not in proving the rule stated in the picture above. 
Also I would like to know how is it solved for a second integral $(n=2)$? just to be convinced with the general rule of $n$th integral.
Thank you.

\begin{align*}
  &\, \int_0^\infty \int_0^t f(t)
  e^{-st}(-s) \left( -\frac{1}{s} \right)
  \,\text{d}t \,\text{d}t
\\
  &\left(
   u = \int_0^t f(t) \, \text{d}t,
  \quad
  \text{d}v = -s e^{-st} \, \text{d}t
  \right)
\\
  =&\, - \frac{1}{s}
    \left.
      \int_0^t f(t) e^{-st} \,\text{d}t \,
    \right|_{0}^\infty
    + \frac{1}{s}
    \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \, \text{d}t
\\
  =&\, f(\infty) e^{-s \infty} \frac{1}{-s} + f(0) + \frac{1}{s} F(s)
  = 0 + \frac{1}{s} F(s)
\end{align*}

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AayYE.jpg).)

Comment: [Laplace Transform of Integral](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYOzTt-gB8A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, but use different variables:

$$\mathscr{L}\left[ \int_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau\right]
  = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}  \int_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau \, dt. $$

We have:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}  \int_0^t f(\tau) \, d\tau \, dt = \int_0^{\infty} s\,e^{-st}  \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, dt. $$

Applying the famous technique, integration by parts:

$$dv = s\, e^{-st} dt \quad \Rightarrow \quad v = -e^{-st}, $$
$$u = \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \quad \Rightarrow \quad du=\frac{1}{s} f(t), $$

so:

$$\int_0^{\infty} s\,e^{-st}  \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, dt. = - \frac{1}{s} e^{-st} \left. \int_0^t f(\tau)\, d\tau \, \right|_{0}^\infty + \frac{1}{s} \int_0^\infty f(t)\, e^{-st} \, dt$$

$$= \frac{1}{s} \int_0^\infty f(t)\, e^{-st} \, dt$$

$$ = \frac{1}{s}\, F(s).$$

Now, we add a second integral:

$$\mathscr{L}\left[ \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma\right] 
  = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \left(  \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \right) dt. $$

Again, we use integration by parts:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \left(  \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \right) dt =  \int_0^{\infty} s\, e^{-st} \left(  \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \right) dt, $$

with:

$$dv = s\, e^{-st} dt \quad \Rightarrow \quad v = -e^{-st}, $$
$$u = \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \quad \Rightarrow \quad du= \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} f(\tau)\, d\tau. $$

Well, this is long:

$$\int_0^{\infty} s\, e^{-st} \left(  \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} \frac{1}{s} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \right) dt = - \frac{1}{s} e^{-st} \left. \int_0^t \int_0^{\sigma} f(\tau) \, d\tau \, d\sigma \, \right|_{0}^\infty + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} f(\tau)\, d\tau, $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{s} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \int_0^t  f(\tau)\, d\tau, $$
$$ = \frac{1}{s}\cdot \frac{1}{s} F(s). $$